# Preencher segundo input ao digitar no primeiro

Tags: input

tenho um formulário html com RAZÃO SOCIAL e NOME FANTASIA, daí queria que quando digitasse no campo "Razão Social" o campo "Nome Fantasia" fosse preenchido automaticamente com o mesmo valor.
Obrigado desde já pela ajuda.

Answer (score 2):

Você pode fazer isso com jquery usando algo assim:

```
$(document).on('keyup', '#razao-social', function() {
    $('#nome-fantasia').val($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: Amigo obrigado pela ajuda, desculpa meu pouquíssimo conhecimento em JavaScript, como eu colocaria isso no meu form?

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#ID_CONTROLE_RAZAO_SOCIAL').on('keyup', function() {
        $('#ID_CONTROLE_NOME_FANTASIA').val($(this).val());
    });
});
```

Coloque esse trecho de código em qualquer tag Script, e de preferência antes do final da tag Body, lembrando de substituir o nome dos ID's dos controles.

Comment: Pessoal obrigado pela ajuda. A princípio não funcionou, daí verifiquei que o meu input só tinha a propriedade name="" e não tinha o id (JavaScript pega o ID) daí acrescentei o ID com o mesmo nome e funcionou!! lembrando de adicionar o <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script> no head! Obrigado pela ajuda Cayo e Ives